# About eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and their relation with the root square of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was trying to obtain the square root of a matrix through the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and there is something that doesn't add up in some of the demonstrations that I observed after getting stuck.

So, being $Q$ the eigenvector column matrix of $A$ and  $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$, we can put $A$ as:

$$ A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} $$

From this is easily deducible that:

$$ A^n = (Q \Lambda Q^{-1})(Q \Lambda Q^{-1})...(Q \Lambda Q^{-1}) = Q \Lambda^n Q^{-1} $$

But the demonstration of this only seems valid for all the natural numbers and I cannot see how it can extend directly for the integer or rational numbers.

Comment: Square root is only well defined for symmetric positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Not every matrix has a square root. For example, consider
$$
            A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$
This has no $2\times 2$ square root $B$. If it did, then $B^4=A^2=0$ would hold, which would mean that the minimal polynomial for $B$ would either be $\lambda$, or $\lambda^2$. However, $B^2=A\ne 0$. So $B=0$ would have to hold, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from what you wrote that if $B=Q\Psi Q^{-1}$, and if $\Psi^2=\Lambda$, then $B^2=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}=A$. So, $B$ is a square root of $A$.

Comment: But is it proven that the $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$ of A and B are the same? The only way to prove it that I can imagine is that those terms are the only ones that don't vary while squaring.

Comment: Yes, it's the same $Q$. I *defined* $B$ as $Q\Psi Q^{-1}$ where $\Psi^2=\Lambda$. Then I proved that $B^2=A$. Where do you see a problem?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to express it. It is related I think to not seeing a strict demonstration of both Q being the same matrix, this is, that both matrixes have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: My answer contains a short proof of the fact that $B=Q\Psi Q^{-1}\wedge\Psi^2=\Lambda\implies B^2=A$. About which step do you have a doubt?